# Modify a Controller to Accept Additional Field in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Ruby on Rails, I have created a blog.  The blog has posts, and comments associated with each post.

I want to add a name field to the comment controller (or model, not sure), so that the commenter is identified.  Since right now it's just a comment that's being added.  The name field should be stored in the database.

What is the best way to accomplish this, once I already have things set up and I just want to modify?  Can scaffold or generate be used at this point?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a database migration file that adds a column to the Comments table in your database. You'll need to adjust your views to display a form field for the commenters name and for the blog to display the name along side the comment. This RoR Guide should get you started
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

You can use Generate to do something like this

```
ruby script/generate migration AddCommentNames
```

And then edit the migration file that appears in `db/migrations` to add something along the lines of

```
add_column :comments, :name, :string
```